# Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-permissions

We are facing strange crash which is happening to some devices with live playstore version of the app, we have error logging setup with firebase crashlytics, smartlook and testfairy - at all 3 places we are getting same error log, suddenly our users started facing this in a stable app.

Here is the full bug report

`Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null. To fix this issue try these steps: • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run` pod install`in the`ios` directory and then clean, rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
• If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. You can use this to get started: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/blob/master/mock.js
If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1943:1018
h@2:1585
d@2:958
o@2:496
Pe@2161:18604
anonymous@2161:18014
Ul@55:66831
ja@55:84504
anonymous@55:82832
Y@177:2883
e@177:400
anonymous@84:1256
k@84:499
callTimers@84:2652
value@36:3556
anonymous@36:673
value@36:2503
value@36:645

```
   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)`
```

We are using react-native-permissions 3.6.1

Since it is only happening with live version of the app we do not have solid reproduction steps. we are using checkNotifications() function on the screen where the app is crashing

`checkNotifications()
.then(({status}) => {

```
    check(
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA
        : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA,
    )
      .then(result => {

      })
      .catch(() => {

      });
  })
  .catch(() => {

  });
```

`};